# Переменная очищает свое значение

Tags: c++, c, криптография

Я писал многопоточный сервер для цифровой подписи сообщений и проверки на подлинность, и во время сохранения в переменную значения логина, она автоматически очищается, я так же использовал дебаггер для проверки где именно я ошибся, и даже если я ввожу вручную значение через дебаггер, оно моментально очищается. Полный код сервера на Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/3mv6ppg7, библиотека взята с Хабра https://habr.com/ru/post/503432/, код клиента https://pastebin.com/YMen0PU8

```
if(isValidCommand(command))
{
    std::string Vlogin,pass;
    Vlogin =parseValidLogin(command);
    pass = parseValidPass(command);
    Valid =  db.Valid(Vlogin,pass);
    if(Valid)
    {
        buffer = VALID +"VALIDATED";
        ThisUsereLogin = Vlogin;
    }
    if(!Valid)
    {
        buffer = VALID+"WRONG_LOGIN_OR_PASSWORD";
    }

}
if(isCreateCommand(command))
{   
    std::string Clogin,pass;
    bool isCanCreate = false;
    Clogin =parseCreateLogin(command);
    pass = parseCreatePass(command);
    isCanCreate = db.AddClient(Clogin, pass);
    
    if(isCanCreate)
    {
        buffer = CREATE+"User_created";
        ThisUsereLogin =Clogin;
    }
    else
    {
        buffer = CREATE+"Login_busy";
    }
```

Comment: Приведите [минимальный пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) в тексте вопроса

Comment: ну или хотя бы покажите место в коде, где переменная "автоматически очистилась"

Comment: При этом сами переменные Clogin и Vlogin не пустые, так как и валидация и создание ключей прошло успешно

Comment: В каком месте кода (отметьте комментарием в нем) Vlogin и Clogin еще заполнены, а где они уже пустые?

Comment: Они заполняются прям в этом if когда от клиента приходит tcp запрос формата CREATE::Lol::Kek
Где первое значение это логин, а второе пароль, после чего эта строка парсится  функциями parseCreateLogin и parseCreatePass, после чего возвращенный логин сначала идет на создание клиента в базе данных, а потом присваивает значение в ThisUsereLogin

Comment: ThisUsereLogin (*у меня английский язык заболел от такого написания*) случайно не глобальная переменная, которую видят и портят все треды сразу?

Comment: Прошу прощения за такие корявые названия переменных, но нет ThisUsereLogin локальная переменная для каждого подключившегося клиента

Comment: Короче, играть в 20 вопросов можно до опупения. Выкладывайте весь код - у меня хрустальный шар барахлит, не показывает, где вы там позабыли мьютекс вкорячить или еще какой atomic

Comment: и makefile https://pastebin.com/DEBfGJcj

Comment: Я правильно понял, что перед `Valid =  db.Valid(Vlogin,pass);` и `isCanCreate = db.AddClient(Clogin, pass);` переменные заполнены, а после них уже пустые? Если да, то надо смотреть реализацию этих функций

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ei7kLt9U полная реализация класса

Comment: @ДжамаловСиявуш, здесь не принято лазить по сторонним ресурсам. Вам надо скомпоновать маленький код, который можно скомпилировать и в котором проявляется ошибка и выложить его в тексте вопроса

Comment: Тут есть такая интересная заковыка, что не зная, где именно ошибка, сложно получить [МВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ДжамаловСиявуш - правильно ли я понимаю, что многопоточность состоит в том, что каждый клиент у вас сидит в своем потоке?

Comment: Да каждый клиент сидит в отдельном потоке

Comment: @gbg, это (получение МВП) не сложно, но может быть утомительно. Отбрасываете кусочек и смотрите,   осталась ли еще ошибка (что-то вроде ловли льва, путем перегораживания пустыни пополам). Вполне вероятно, что двигаясь таким образом автор сам эту ошибку и найдет

Comment: @avp - это хорошо, если человеку известно, что он ищет. Потому что в данном коде, проблема в полностью (то есть, *наглухо*) отсутствующих блокировках (или других способах обеспечения корректности параллельной программы) где бы то ни было.

Comment: @gbg, понятно (всегда считал, что автомобиль это самое страшное оружие в руках молодого бойца)

Answer (score 2):

Если каждый клиент сидит в своем персональном потоке, проблема состоит в этом:

У вас там `map`, который называется `storage`, в который функция `AddClient` лезет без мьютекса. Да и вообще, мьютекс присутствует только в виде `#include<mutex>`